# Same website on same domain name with different extensions - i.e. .com and .co.uk

Tags: dns

What is best practice for doing this? Should I have duplicate content at each domain or should I redirect from one to the the other, i.e. all traffic to the .co.uk domain redirected to the .com domain?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to send them all to one web server.

By default the server will not care which domain is pointed at it and will show the home page as domainx.com if you to it from domainx.com.

However there are two possible issues with this that come to mind:

- The person who created the website hopefully only used relative links. (The contact us button points to contactus.htm instead of http://domainx.com/contactus.htm ) If not, some links might change the user from domainx.co.uk to domainx.com.
- Search Engine Optimisation: Its better SEO wise if all the links to your site point to one domain name rather than appearing as several less popular sites.

You can get everyone on the same site by using a RewriteRule or 301 Redirect to the primary site. Or you can make every hyperlink on the site absolute and point to the primary domain.